# How to give regular expression for name with space & min max length?

Tags: regex

Assume only characters are in English and space is allowed

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\s|_)?[a-zA-Z]*
```

Playground:- https://regex101.com/r/1vM2H3/1

"Satish Patro" (accepted)

"Satish " (accepted, but shouldn't be accepted)

But, two things are not handled

1. if underscore is there, it should have letters at the end

   So, "satish " not allowed
2. How to handle regex for matching length for min = 1, max = 20

How to handle those things

Comment: I don't see a question in your post. Also, that regex does not match "Satish Patro", did you mean `\s` instead of `\\s`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans updated. Wrote in a hurry

Comment: Please show more sample passing and failing inputs.

Comment: I have given in double quotes & online playground

Comment: For future reference: (1) say which language you're using, because each one has its own regex conventions and extensions. (2) explain _why_ you need it: is this username validation (because why roll your own, use any of tens of premade validators). (3) please write your post [as a normal question](/help/how-to-ask) next time, because this reads like you just copied a homework assignment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why dont you try this?

```
((?=.*_)^[a-zA-Z_\s]{1,19}[a-zA-Z]$)|((?!.*_)^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,20}$)
```

No Space and UnderScore as first character

```
((?=.*_)^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s_]{1,18}[a-zA-Z]$)|((?!.*_)^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]{1,19}$)
```

Comment: This one can accept 40+ characters also. FYI, I have not downvoted

Comment: I think it doesnt. Can you show me the case ? https://regex101.com/r/1vM2H3/3

Comment: correct, character wise 20 it's accepting. But, it accepts spaace/ underscore as 1st character. Can that be avoidable?

Comment: I had no idea about lookahead. I will read about that.

Comment: I have edited my answer to your needs

Comment: it is allowing space at the end "B " & "_s" at the start. https://regex101.com/r/1vM2H3/4 . Only thing I changed in you regex is replaced '\s' with ' ', as \s can take tab, newline etx

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify that you want to match the whole string

^[a-zA-Z]+\s?[a-zA-Z]*$

Comment: that only I have given, but in this one, I can't able to check the length. FYI, I have not downvoted